# Difference between Unbounded Wildcard Types and Bounded Wildcard Types?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have the following two classes:

```
class SomeClassA<F extends E> { }

class SomeClassB<? extends E> { }
```

**What is the difference and the limitation between SomeClassA and SomeClassB?**

Comment: The second one doesn't even compile.

Comment: Best tutorial and explenantion about wildcards: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 1):

It may gives you some idea

`class SomeClassB<? extends E> { }`:

`A` class with an unbounded type parameter. Its elements are of a specific, but unknown, type. The elements must all be the same type.

`class SomeClassA<F extends E> { }`:

`A` class with a type parameter called `F`. The supplied type for `F` must be of a type that extends `E`, or it is not a valid type for the parameter.